# Why does .position() return "static"?

Tags: jquery

I have an element, and when I return the position, it just says "static"

Any ideas?

*EDIT*

```
$("#testED").position().top
```

This returns "undefined"

Comment: @melhosseiny http://api.jquery.com/position/

Comment: What does `$("#testED").position()`  return? Can you `console.log()` it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the position values use something like this:

```
<script>
var o = $("#testED");
var position = o.position();
alert(o.left);
alert(o.top);
</script>
```

Comment: There's my problem.. it returns undefined

Comment: Do you really have an element with id = testED?

Comment: Yes. because $("#testED").position() returns "static"

Comment: @Shamoon there must be something else wrong - as shown by @Town's JSFiddle, this works.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6TjJn/2/ - it's so strange. Works JUST FINE on fiddle, but not so much in my application